# Replace ^A symbol with space with a tab

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file where the lines look something like this:

```
 878803058210225308^A12:41:46^A12:41:46^A1^A1
```

I want to be able to remove the ^A characters. I have tried the tr command but I have not be able to get what I want. I tried this:

```
tr ^A \\t < myfile1  > myfile2
```

What would be the best way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^A` is actually a single character ascii 0x01. It just has a "nickname" of control-A. So you can use this to replace it.

```
tr '\01' '\t'
```

Comment: This woks perfectly. Thank you very much